# VHDL if statements in process driving multiple outputs per if statement

Tags: if-statement, vhdl

I have a weird question which sounds self explanatory in vhdl, but the code does not output to an oscilloscope even though the logic seems okay.  I need to drive 0's and 1's for each bit in the vector below, and I need to do this with combinations of sliderswitches.  I am using the Digilent Nexys 3.

My problem is that when I run this code or any code that has more than 3 outputs per if statement, one of the outputs does not output to logic '1' when given the right combination.

I gave my code below, which seems extremely simple.  Can someone tell me why I can only output 3 things per if statement?  I need to be able to output 20 or more signals per if statement.

I have tried everything I can think of, from using bit_vector, to using different syntax.  Any help on why I can only get 3 outputs at most would be greatly appreciated.

```
Library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use work.all ;


entity pulse_gen_toVGA is port (
clk_50,sw0,sw1,sw2,sw3 : in std_logic ;
rst : in std_logic;
output : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));


end pulse_gen_toVGA;

architecture top of pulse_gen_toVGA is


begin



process(sw0,sw1,sw2,sw3)
begin

if (sw0='0' and sw1='0' and sw2='0' and sw3='0') then
null;
end if;

if(sw0='1') then
output<="0001";
elsif(sw1='1') then
output<="0010";
elsif(sw2='1') then
output<="0100";
elsif(sw3='1') then
output<="1000";
end if;


end process;

end top ;
```

Here is my ucf file of the outputs that I am using.

```
net "clk_50" loc="v10";
net "output<0>" loc="t12";
net "output<1>" loc="n10";
net "output<2>" loc="p11";
net "output<3>" loc="h3";


net "sw0" loc="t10";
net "sw1" loc="t9";
net "sw2" loc="v9";
net "sw3" loc="m8";
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code is not exactly O.K.. Let's see:

```
if (sw0='0' and sw1='0' and sw2='0' and sw3='0') then
    null;
end if;
```

This `if` does nothing, except waste precious bytes on your hard drive and several microseconds of cpu time everytime you synthesise or simulate. Having these lines or not changes absolutely nothing, so might as well remove them.

```
if(sw0='1') then
    output<="0001";
elsif(sw1='1') then
    output<="0010";
elsif(sw2='1') then
    output<="0100";
elsif(sw3='1') then
    output<="1000";
end if;
```

What happens if none of the switches is '1'? Implicitely, that a signal must not change its value if it is not assigned, which requires a memory element since when all switches are '0', `output` depends on the last switch that was active.

In that case, the synthesizer will infer a **latch**. Latches are known to behave erratically and should really only be used by experts. They appear every time you forget to assign a signal in one logical path of a combinational process.

You have two choices to *fix* your code, either you add an `else` to your if statement, setting `output` to 0 for example, or you use a *proper* memory element known as a **register**. In the first case, you will have a combinational circuit, containing only logic gates with no latch/register. In the second case, you will have the same behaviour as the latch circuit, but without the erratically of the latch. Here's how to implement a register:

```
process(clk_50)
begin
    if rising_edge(clk_50) then
        if(sw0='1') then
            output<="0001";
        elsif(sw1='1') then
            output<="0010";
        elsif(sw2='1') then
            output<="0100";
        elsif(sw3='1') then
            output<="1000";
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

I have to add that the register route is not entirely fine, and encourage you to search for metastability, asynchronous input and resynchronization. Basically, using asynchronous signals (like your switches) without synchronizing it can cause problem.

Finally, it may not solve your problem, but we can look into that once you have a "clean" code.

Comment: Hi Jonathan.  I tried using the register approach, and setting the else statements to logic 0 and just using concurrent statements as well and neither seem to work.  Any ideas to what doesn't allow me to output more than three things per if statement?  I need to have each if statement send at least twenty signals.

Comment: As @david-koontz pointed out, the logic is fine. Are you sure your UCF is correct? Try something simpler, like `output <= sw0 & sw1 & sw2 & sw3;` to make sure your inputs and outputs are connected properly.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Was using a four channel oscilloscope and one of the ports on the oscilloscope was broken.  The code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Before you go making changes there are a couple of thing you can check.

There are not outputs labelled `output` in Nexys3_Master.ucf.  Show us how (where) `output` goes that you're detecting it doesn't occur.

We can't replicate your problem with what you've provided, it isn't an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Next, simulate your design.

Here is a simple testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity pgtv_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of pgtv_tb is
    signal clk_50:  std_logic;
    signal sw0, sw1, sw2, sw3:  std_logic;
    signal rst:     std_logic;
    signal output:  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
begin
DUT:
    entity work.pulse_gen_toVGA
        port map (
            clk_50 => clk_50,
            sw0 => sw0,
            sw1 => sw1,
            sw2 => sw2,
            sw3 => sw3,
            rst => rst,
            output => output
        );

STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw0 <= '0';
        sw1 <= '0';
        sw2 <= '0';
        sw3 <= '0';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw0 <= '1';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw0 <= '0';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw1 <= '1';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw1 <= '0';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw2 <= '1';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw2 <= '0';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw3 <= '1';
        wait for 100 ms;
        sw3 <= '0';
        wait for 100 ms;
        wait;       
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And it produces:

[image: pgtv_tb.png]
*(clickable)*

Now the first thing we see is the inferred latches Jonathan Drolet was concerned with from the null statement in the first if statement.

Changing all the switch inputs to '0' didn't affect `output`, this happens four more times in the simulation.

But you can see we actually do get four outputs, which says

> ... when I run this code or any code that has more than 3 outputs per if statement, one of the outputs does not output to logic '1' when given the right combination

Isn't evident in the VHDL code.  And that strongly suggests there's something wrong somewhere getting `output` to show up, and it's not evident in your code.

(Your code doesn't reproduce the problem for which you are asking help, regardless of whether you want those latches there or not).

Comment: Hi David.  Above I posted the code for the ucf file above.  I am outputting to the pmod ports on the Digilent nexys 3 fpga.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice net `"output<3>" loc="h3";` is on the C connector while the other 3 are on the A connector according to the Master UCF.  Are you sure you're looking in the right place?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Was using a four channel oscilloscope and one of the ports on the oscilloscope was broken.  The code works fine!

Comment: There's a good argument for simulating designs, particular if there's a problem.